# What if all nodes are not in a defined pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, hazelcast, max-pool-size

I have a hazel cast instance defined in my setup.

```
<tcp-ip enabled="true">
<member>SeverA</member>
<member>SeverB</member>
<member>SeverC</member>
<member>SeverD</member>
<member>SeverE</member>
<member>SeverF</member>
<member>SeverG</member>
<member>SeverH</member>
<member>SeverI</member>
<member>SeverJ</member>
</tcp-ip>
```

And this pool is defined onservers for SeverA to ServerH

BUT the pools defined on ServerI & ServerJ are :

```
<tcp-ip enabled="true">
<member>SeverI</member>
<member>SeverJ</member>
</tcp-ip>
```

Do you guys think this will be a problem for ServerA to ServerH ? Since I & J do not see them ?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a problem. Whenever a node joins an already existing cluster, the whole topology will be changed. In theory you only need 1 or 2 known entry points (servers with fixed IP addresses) to build a cluster.

The member definitions DO NOT define visibility, it is just a list of "possibly reachable IP addresses" to connect to.